# Switching Plasma theme from the command line

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, kde, themes, plasma-5

I would like to switch between dark and light themes easily (Default Breeze and dark Breeze themes) without having to navigate to System Settings > Global themes > Click on theme > click Apply.

So I was wondering if there existed a way to quickly switch between already installed themes without using the mouse, maybe running a previously made Bash script?

If such a way were feasible then I would be able to fire those scripts with [this On/Off plasmoid](https://store.kde.org/p/1297839). So, is there a way to change Global Plasma Theme from the command line?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be done with `lookandfeeltool` that shall come preinstalled on any recent version of Plasma 5. To use it, type on a terminal window:

1. `lookandfeeltool --list` to get a list of all available themes on your system.
2. `lookandfeeltool -a CopyPastaFromTheOutputAbove` to change to your desired theme.

---

All credits go to user Skyite Ovexion on the KDE's Telegram group.

Comment: This command changes the Global Theme. I wonder if there's a separate command for Plasma Theme/Style only, otherwise perhaps the only way could be a command like this: `sed -i -e "s/name=breeze-dark/name=breeze/" "$HOME/.config/plasmarc" && plasmashell --replace`

Comment: Saved my life, I just scr*wd up with a borked plasma style.

Answer (score 0):

`kwriteconfig5` seems to be an actual answer. But there is no documentation on the Internet.

For example, to switch to the default Breeze theme the command is:

```
kwriteconfig5 --file kdeglobals --group KDE --key widgetStyle Breeze
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this and it worked for me with Kubuntu 2204 to open the System Settings for root without a root profile: `sudo -i systemsettings5`.